# Does both NULL and nullptr point to same address or NULL points to nowhere? (I have seen in many places that nullptr points to zero address)

Tags: c++, null, c++14, null-pointer

Does both NULL and nullptr point to same address or NULL points to nowhere?
(I have seen in many places that nullptr points to zero address where memory is inaccessible)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: not sure the standard says something about this, but I doubt it exists a compiler where `NULL != nullptr` is true

Comment: [nullptr, the pointer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks, just learned that is required _also_ by the standard, not only by common sense

Comment: Yes [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/) is hard to beat. Best C++ reference on the net - by far. (even with the debatable change to external search....)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In cppreference when I checked NULL there in note I found type of NULL in C++ in not void* unlike that in C. But as I am not that old in programming I couldn't conclude what is the type of NULL. Can you please help?

Comment: `NULL` is specified as expanding to a null pointer constant.   `nullptr` denotes a pointer literal, of type `nullptr_t`, for which there exists a conversion to any null pointer constant.   So `NULL` (as defined in standard headers) and `nullptr` will compare equal (after appropriate implicit conversions are performed).   `NULL` may expand to a value with integral type, so it doesn't necessarily point at anything.

Comment: A null or NULL or `nullptr` or 0-valued pointer are all the same and don't point to anything, by coinvention of the C and C++ languages as applicable. It is not the case that address 0 is reserved, which would be an action of the operating system if it existed, which it doesn't.

Comment: @user207421 Do you mean that neither NULL nor nullptr are pointers?

Comment: I didn't say anything about it actually, as you didn't ask it in your question, but NULL is a zero, `nullptr` is a `nullptr_t`, and 0 is a zero, and all three of them *as pointer values* don't point to anything.

Comment: @user207421 Ok got it. Now almost clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be useful to clear up some terminology. A pointer *points to* an object. The *value* of a pointer is an address value. There is a special address value for pointers that do *not* point to an object. We call such pointers "null pointers". When you assign the `NULL` or `nullptr` values to a pointer, it becomes a null pointer.

Since all null pointers compare equal, `static_cast<void*>(NULL) == static_cast<void>(nullptr)`.

Comment: I understand that nullptr is a pointer but is NULL a pointer?

Comment: @Vic: `nullptr` absolutely is not a pointer. It's a `std::nullptr_t` value. That's a special type, which can be _converted_ to any pointer type.

Comment: Oh people call nullptr a pointer just for simplicity but actually it isn't. And what about NULL ?

Comment: @Vic: Same basic idea: You use that value to initialize null pointers. Its exact type is a bit vague but it's also not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `nullptr` is C++09 addition (well, it was included in C++0x which was going to be released somewhere that time and ended up as C++11). So prior to this there was no `nullptr` and `NULL` was all you had.

The whole point was to make null values unambiguous. There is no guarantee that `NULL` is `0`. It may be `0L` for example. It can also be `42`. Passing it to overloaded functions could cause unexpected behavior. To avoid such ambiguity the new strongly typed `nullptr` was introduced and now you can create overloads or even templates precisely to handle this case. Now you can overload your constructor.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7faac5903a02e365

```
#include <iostream>

void func(int* ptr)
{
    std::cout << "ptr" << std::endl;   
}

void func(size_t size)
{
    std::cout << "size" << std::endl;   
}

void func(std::nullptr_t)
{
    std::cout << "nullptr" << std::endl;   
}

int main()
{    
    int myValue(10);
    func(myValue);
    func(&myValue);
    func(nullptr);
    
    // Good luck with this
    // func(NULL);
}
```

To be precise here, `NULL` is constant literal that is implicitly convertible to any pointer and has `null pointer value`. The same applies to `nullptr`, so in both cases you are guaranteed that they will produce pointer with `null pointer value`. It does not mean that it is `0` and technically it does not even guarantee that it will be the same value, at least I did not find a proof that there has to be just one `null pointer value`. Obviously it would be ridiculous to implement more than one of them but if it's not specified, it's not guaranteed. In any modern implementation the pointer created from `NULL` and `nullptr` will point to the same `null pointer value` address which is treated by compiler differently from any other, presumably valid address.

Most of all, nullptr does not have a value. It can't be converted to any number, it can only be converted to any pointer type. You can't say that `nullptr` is zero because it is not. It **converts** to any pointer type which then converted to numeric value will be `null pointer value` whatever it is on given platform/compiler.

Comment: NULL gets confused which function to use even in case 2 functions as well, very good practical usage you've shown.

Answer (score -1):

`NULL` is just a pre-processor constant for `0`. And because address is a number, the address `0` is reserved for a 'bad' address. But nothing stops you from assigning `NULL` to any number variable since it will be replaced with `0`. A `nullptr` is a special constant, that will only work with pointers. But it's essentially pointer-only constant for `0`.

Comment: So NULL is not a pointer and neither points to anywhere?

Comment: There's nothing stopping an implementation from defining `NULL` as `nullptr`. You can't rely on it being `0` (which would be a horrible thing to rely on anyway). In fact, Microsoft attempted to change it to `nullptr`, but had too much broken code.

Comment: In our company code base, I indeed redefined `NULL` as `nullptr`.

Comment: by default, a bad address is address `0`. And this is true for most OSs, since they're using virtual memory. Even if the actual 'bad' address is not `0`, the OS maps `0` to that address.
The reason because `NULL` is replaced with `nullptr` is that nothing stops you from using `NULL` as a number, and not an address. And this is totally valid, but it's a bad habit. So the `nullptr` was created. To improve clarity of the code.

Comment: @ШерифГрей, An implementation doing `#define NULL nullptr` would certainly stop you from using `NULL` as a number.

Comment: but most c-programs rely on the fact, that `NULL` is just `0`. Breaking that would be not a very good idea. Because you cannot be sure, if nobody didn't use `NULL` as a number. And breaking the existing code is usually not recommended

Comment: @ШерифГрей  nullptr is clear for me now but I am still confused about if NULL a pointer or not.

Comment: The address 0 is not reserved. The *value* zero is reserved. Not the same thing.

Comment: @Vic • `NULL` is not a pointer, it's a macro defined to be 0 or some compiler specific token semantically means the same thing, which is a "magic value" indicating a null pointer.  The address value of 0 is a reserved value to indicate null-ness for pointers (there's a wrinkle that if the platform "null" address is not 0, the compiler has to do the right thing in those situations).  `nullptr` is a keyword that indicates a null pointer, and is convertible to any pointer.

Comment: @ШерифГрей -- in C, the macro 'NULL' is often '(void*)0'. In C++ it's typically just plain `0`, because C++ is more strict than C about promoting `void*`.